# Make table cells equal size (width/height) not counting headers

Tags: html, css

How do I force table to take some space for headers (vertical and horizontal) and make all other cells (`<td>`) equal size no matter what?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th><th...
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th><td...
  </tr>
  <tr...
</table>
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGVm5/)

Would like all grey squares to have same size... any way to do it via CSS?

Comment: Setting the height and width of the td cell would not work? http://jsfiddle.net/5gBTR/

Comment: @Philibobby it only works as far as cells are empty...

Answer (score 6):

For cell of equal size add this rule

```
table  {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Further information on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)

If you also need to reduce the height of your cells just remove `height=100%` from the table and set an height to the `<th>` elements

Comment: After setting fixed `<th>` width and height, it actually works :-) thank you!

Comment: Oh... it doesn't work, as cells are being resized when content is added :/ [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGVm5/1/)

Comment: have you tried to remove height=100% from the table and set an height to the <th> elements as I suggested? :)

Comment: if you can't set the height how could you obtain cells of equal size with different amount of text?

Comment: That was what I was asking about ;-)

Comment: @FlashThunder I think you need to explain better what you want. You can either have the cells be the same size, or have the table at 100% height/width. This is mutually exclusive.

Comment: Why is that? Exclusive because of CSS limitations? Because logically it is not exclusive at all. I don't need them to be squares.